# i need to send a post request from the worklight adapter

Tags: javascript, adapter, ibm-mobilefirst

i am using IBM Worklight i need to send a post request to the server from the worklight adapter i am calling in this way i am supposed to get xml content as a response from the server but am getting HTML and it is failing kindly help me 
same post request am sending through the REST client XML output is coming perfectly

my code in adapter is

```
    function showAttributes()
    {
        var truevar ="True";
        var pubvar ="public";
        var gridvar = "GridView";
        var gvar ="Grid View 1 ";

        var request = '<rdf:RDF xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:rs="http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/DataAccess/tests/result-set#" xmlns:rrmNav="http://com.ibm.rdm/navigation#" xmlns:rrmViewdata="http://com.rdm/viewdata#" xmlns:rt="https://crizz.net/qw/views" xmlns:rm="http://www.crizz.com/xmlns/rdm/rdf/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" xmlns:rql="http://www.crizz.com/xmlns/rdm/rql/" xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#">' +
        '<rtm:View rdf:about="">' + 
        '<rtm:rowquery rdf:parseType="Resource"> ' +

                       ' <rdf:Seq>' +
                            '<rdf:li rdf:resource="https://jazz.net/rtm/folders/_maPswFcdEeCVbIiWC7_0yA"/>'+
                        '</rdf:Seq>' +
                   ' </rql:e2>' +
                    '<rql:op>' + invar + '</rql:op>' +
                '</rdf:_1>' +
            '</rql:where>' +
        '</rtm:rowquery>' +
        '<rtm:displayBaseProperties rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#boolean">' + truevar + '</rtm:displayBaseProperties>' +
        '<rrmNav:scope>' + pubvar + '</rrmNav:scope>'+
        '<rtm:ofType>' + gridvar + '</rtm:ofType>' +
        '<dcterms:description> </dcterms:description>' +
        '<dcterms:title>' + gvar +'</dcterms:title>' +
    '</rtm:View>' +
    '</rdf:RDF>';
        var input = {
            method : 'post',
            returnedContentType : 'application/xml',
            path : lpath,
            headers : {
                'RP-Request-Type' : 'private',

                       },

                       body : {
                            contentType: 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
                            content: request.toString()
                        },
                        parameters : {
                            'oslc.query' : 'execute=true&fullObject=false&size=20&count=true&page=1&reuse=false&'
                        }

        };

        return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);

}
```

Is there any mistake in sending the POST request ..please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: can anyone help me in resolving this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah upgrading the worklight 5.0.5 to 5.0.6 solved my problem thanks to Idan Adar a lot

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to start small with a very simple procedure that does POST. [Follow the HTTP adapter module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/04_02_HTTP_adapter_-_Communicating_with_HTTP_back-end_systems.pdf).

Comment: thanks a lot idan adar .In the document u have referred to me the body content is stored in a variable as it is .if am doing the same it is not allowing me its giving errors also i have downloaded the sample code  from this url http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html communicating with HTTP backend systems and i have just inported into eclipse even that gives me the same error. please help me